# rosserial_arduino generate dependent packages before make_libraries

Tags: arduino, rosserial, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I ensure my custom message packages is made before my arduino packages attempts to build?

I have an arduino package that relies on a custom message package, relative_nav_msgs. In a standard ROS package I would call $ add_dependencies(node_name relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp) to ensure that the messages are being built before I try building my node.

I feel like I need to call something similar before calling the rosserial_generate_ros_lib command in the CMake file. Without it, make_libraries fails to generate headers for my relative_nav_msgs packages. I found that I can hack make_libraries.py by adding a 15 second delay before it tries to generate ros_lib, this allows time for the relative_nav_msgs to be built. I would prefer a legit method though.

I have included the packages CMake, package.xml, and the firmware CMake. Thank you for any help!

Package CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rc_read)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rosserial_arduino
  rosserial_client
  relative_nav_msgs
)

catkin_package()

rosserial_generate_ros_lib(
 PACKAGE rosserial_arduino
 SCRIPT make_libraries.py
)

rosserial_configure_client(
  DIRECTORY firmware
  TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TOOLCHAIN}
)

rosserial_add_client_target(firmware rc_read ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(firmware rc_read-upload)
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>rc_read</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The rc_read package</description>

  <maintainer email="paul@todo.todo">paul</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>relative_nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosserial_arduino</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosserial_client</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>relative_nav_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosserial_arduino</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosserial_client</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
</package>
```

and finally my firmware CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

include_directories(${ROS_LIB_DIR})

# Remove this if using an Arduino without native USB (eg, other than Leonardo)
add_definitions(-DUSB_CON)

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libraries)

generate_arduino_firmware(rc_read
  SRCS rc_read.cpp ${ROS_LIB_DIR}/time.cpp
  BOARD uno
  PORT /dev/ttyACM0
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200995/rosserial_arduino-generate-dependent-packages-before-make_libraries/) by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and solved it like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rc_read)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rosserial_arduino
  rosserial_client
  relative_nav_msgs
)

catkin_package()

rosserial_generate_ros_lib(
 PACKAGE rosserial_arduino
 SCRIPT make_libraries.py
)

add_dependencies(rc_read_ros_lib 
    relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
    relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages
    relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
    relative_nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
)

rosserial_configure_client(
  DIRECTORY firmware
  TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TOOLCHAIN}
)

rosserial_add_client_target(firmware rc_read ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(firmware rc_read-upload)
```

---

Originally posted by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) with karma: 70 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1